# Maven: Can't copy file to WEB-INF\lib\endorsed

Tags: maven

I've got a Maven project and I need it to copy a jar file from `WEB-INF\lib` to `WEB-INF\lib\endorsed`. The jar file gets added `WEB-INF\lib` via a standard Maven dependency. I've been told that the [maven-resources-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/) is the way to make this happen.

This works copying a file from test directories on my hard drive but gives me a `"skip non existing resourceDirectory"` warning no matter how I configure this to use the actual file.

Below is the maven-resources-plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/lib/endorsed</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/lib</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>jaxws-api-2.2.jar</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? WAR dependencies are supposed to be in `WEB-INF/lib`

Comment: Why would you like to put jaxws-api into endorsed dir? Which not make simply part of the war file?

Comment: We need to support some very old servlet containers, some of which have much older versions of this and other libraries.
Placing a copy of these libraries in the endorsed directory gives us a reliable way to override their use so we can use newer versions in our app.